# xPlore1.0 Index Server

Tags: indexing, documentum, documentum6.5

Its a clean installation, no fulltext application installed before.
but i can see both FAST and xPlore folders created in C:\Documentum\fulltext\   right after i finished xPlore installation.

I dont know, why the Content Server point to FAST Plugin?Here is the log:

```
 [DM_FULLTEXT_T_QUERY_PLUGIN_VERSION]info:  
 "Loaded FT Query Plugin:    
   C:\SOFT\Documentum\product\6.6/bin/FASTQueryPlugin.dll, 
  API Interface version: Fast Data Search c++ api v. 2.0.82, 
 Build number: HEAD; May 28 2010 15:24:42, 
 FT Engine version: FAST Instream 4.3"
```

Can u advise me how to point to Xplore plugin instead of FASTQuery Plugin?